# How can I add custom Template for products through custom theme?

Tags: magento2

I have my created a Custom theme for products but I am getting old product page I want my custom product page here is my xml..

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-left" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- this is code to add new tab start -->
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.details">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="deliveryinfo.tab" as="deliveryinfo" template="product/view/delivery_info.phtml" group="detailed_info" >
                <arguments>
                    <argument translate="true" name="title" xsi:type="string">Delivery Information</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <!-- this is code to add new tab end -->
    </body>
</page>
```

I know I am doing some mistake I don;t know what it is..

Comment: Did you select your custom theme in you store configuration?

Answer (score -1):

You must have installed it using composer. 
So have a look here:

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/
```

There is no view.phtml. The product view is generated via the

`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file. All seperate .phtml files for the blocks can be found in the above template path.

Comment: I have tried it with my custom module.. I ab able to display block on product page but I cant change toe page for product.Can you help me with xml code I have tried everything I could.

Comment: This directory exist but I can't find view.phtml file in it.

Comment: There is no view.phtml file. The full view is generated via the `layout/catalog_product_view.xml` as Jay explained in his answer.

Comment: You must have it installed using composer? Whut??

Comment: @SwAt.Be Are you drunk? You do realize my answer was posted way before the question was edited! Maybe you should downvote with a little more care and do some research first!

Answer (score -1):

You can find the default file in

> /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

To override this xml, you can create your catalog_product_view.xml in your custom module.

Comment: ok I have edited my question may be this will give you an idea of what I want.

Comment: try to add `<referenceContainer name="content">` next to `<body>` tag

Comment: custom module? Custom theme you mean. You can do it with a module but he is asking for a custom theme